# how to calculate date and time in call logs

Tags: android, calllog

Does anyone know how to display the call log details for individual calls? When I go into my call history, the only times shown are "1 hour ago, 3 hours ago, yesterday, 2 days ago" etc. Is there any way to view the actual time and date for a call?
    Also, I noticed that when looking at this information for a text message, the "sent" time is inaccurate. Someone can text me at 12:51 AM and the phone will show, "sent at 6:31 PM, received at 12:51 AM". Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
Cursor callLogCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
        if (callLogCursor != null) {
            while (callLogCursor.moveToNext()) {

                String name = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));

                String number = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));

                long dateTimeMillis = callLogCursor.getLong(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE));

                String duration = callLogCursor.getString(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));

                int callType = callLogCursor.getInt(callLogCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE));

                Date date = new Date(dateTimeMillis);
                String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
                        .format(date);

                if (name == null)
                    name = "Unknown";
                int type = 0;
                switch (callType) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    type = R.drawable.out;
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    type = R.drawable.in;
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    type = R.drawable.miss;
                    break;
                }




    Thanks for your help!
```

Comment: I didnt execute your code but the concept of getting time of call log is pretty much the same. You get the date from call log database and convert into your desired format. About the other problem I dont have any idea about how sim log timings are stored but even I observed the same. If you have queries with your code, can you give more details about the problem? may be with error log? Thanks,
siddu.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code for for getting date and time of call from call log

```
    Cursor callDetailCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC limit 50");
    int phoneNumber= callDetailCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int callType=callDetailCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int callDate=callDetailCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int callDuration=callDetailCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int isReadint=callDetailCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.IS_READ);

    Log.i(">>CAllDetails", "getsCallLogs" );

    if(callDetailCursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        while(callDetailCursor.moveToNext())
        {
String phoneNumberString=callDetailCursor.getString(phoneNumber);
String  contactName= getContactName(CallDetails.this, phoneNumberString);
String callTypeString =callDetailCursor.getString(callType);
String callDateString=callDetailCursor.getString(callDate);
String callDurationString=callDetailCursor.getString(callDuration);
Date callDayTime=new Date(Long.valueOf(callDateString));//converting readable date 

            int callCode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeString);
            int calldur=Integer.parseInt(callDurationString);
            if (callCode==2 && calldur>=1)
            {




String location[]=dbTools.getLocation(phoneNumberString);
String addtolist= "Name :"+contactName+"\n"+
                        "Phone Number: "+phoneNumberString+"\n"+"Call Duration :"+
                        callDurationString+" Seconds\n"+"Call Date: "+callDayTime+"\n"+
                location[0]+" "+location[1];
                callArrayList.add(addtolist);


            }
        }
    }callDetailCursor.close();
  }
```